# MySQL query execution return value?

Tags: mysql, execution

I'm constructing an adapter for MySQL in PHP and I was wondering what should MySQL query execution method return? Should it return a result set? Or the last id / affected rows?

Comment: An adapter for what?  PHP already knows how to talk to MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql_query()` returns a result set on success, or `false` if something went wrong.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Hi, yes I know, but is that the most preferred way?